# React redux: how to clear the redux store state on back button press

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, back

I am using react redux combination with following structure:

```
<div>
  // Material ui autocomplete component which sets value in redux store
  <Switch>
  <Route exact path="/abc"><CompA/></Route>
<Route path="/abc/add"><CompB/></Route>
</Switch>
</div>
```

If I am on /abc/add page and I click on browser back button it is not clearing the store but if I refresh the page after that it clears the store. How can I clear it on back button press?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` cleanup function or `componentWillUnmount` function to clear redux state.

For example:

**store.js**

```
export const resetStore = () => ({
  type: STORE_NAME_RESET
});

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case STORE_NAME_RESET:
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**CompB.js**

```
// React hooks

const CompB = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    return dispatch(resetStore());
  }, []);

  return <div></div>;
};

// React class component

class CompB extends React.Component {
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.resetStore();
  }
}

export default connect(null, { resetStore })(AddTodo)
```

Comment: This will not cause any issue when I go to /abc/add from /abc page R8?  It won't clear the store in that case R8?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this; set the action you want the back button to perform in action.js

```
export const RESET_ON_BACK_BUTTON = "RESET_ON_BACK_BUTTON"; 
export const onButtonReset = () => ({
type: RESET_ON_BACK_BUTTON,
});
```

then set your reducer.js file like this

```
case RESET_ON_BACK_BUTTON:
      return {
        ...state,
        backToPreviousPageInProgress: false,
        previousPageData: null,
      };
```

then invoke onButtonReset() like this

```
onClick = () => onButtonReset();
```